# devise/omniauth issue using pow - working on rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, rack-pow

I'm using [pow](http://pow.cx/) to host my rails app locally.

I've added devise and am trying to get omniauth to work following [these steps](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview).

when I visit http://my_site.dev/users/auth/twitter I get the following error -

```
URI::InvalidURIError

the scheme http does not accept registry part: my_site.dev (or bad hostname?)
```

Using the internal rails server works fine, visiting http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/auth/twitter works as expected.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to change something within pow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hostnames are not allowed to include underscores. Try this:

```
$ mv ~/.pow/my_site ~/.pow/my-site
```

The site will now be available under `http://my-site.dev/`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit your etc/hosts and set host there next go to twitter configuration page and set this url there. Probably it is set to localhost or something like this so he is not eager to trust it :).